# nZ is not ring isomorphism to mZ if n and m are 2 distinct positive integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is it necessary to prove this ??? Can it not be shown simply like 2Z is not ring isomorphism to 3Z , when n=2 and m=3.